# call servlet from javascript on pressing TAB key

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, servlets

I have two text boxes in my jsp page. After entering data on first text box when user will press TAB key, then automatically control will call a servlet(in javascript) then will fill the 2nd textbox. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could subscribe to the [`.keydown()`](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/) event of the first textbox and if the key was TAB trigger an AJAX request to the servlet:

```
$(function() {
    // subscribe to the keydown event
    $('#text1').keydown(function(e) {
        // when a key is pressed check if its code was 9 (TAB)
        if (e.which == 9) {
            // if TAB was pressed send an AJAX request
            // to the server passing it the currently 
            // entered value in the first textbox
            $.ajax({
                url: '/someservlet/',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { value: $(this).val() },
                success: function(result) {
                    // when the AJAX succeeds update the value of the 
                    // second textbox using the result returned by the server
                    // In this example we suppose that the servlet returns
                    // the following JSON: {"foo":"bar"}
                    $('#text2').val(result.foo);
                }
            });    
        }
    });
});
```

Here's a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JLJ3f/).

Comment: thanks..but in place of url, will i write the servlet name? can you please tell me that .keydown() in first textbox? please show me a demo in no wrap(head)

Comment: @tom, you will write the url to which your servlet is configured to listen to. Usually its the name. Test calling the url in your browser address bar first to ensure that your servlet works. That's the first step. Also look at my answer for a `no wrap(head)` demo. All you need to do is to wrap your code in a `$(document).ready(function() { ... });` or `$(function() { ... });`. This will ensure that the `.keydown` event registration will happen only when the DOM is fully loaded and all elements are present. If you put this script just before the closing `</body>` you don't need it.

Comment: ya..i got it, just one doubt Darin. I received the value of 2nd textbox as bar and can i place in the value of 2nd textbox like: <input type="text" id="text2" value="//here i want to display bar"/> , i am getting confused..please help me little bit by explaining

Comment: @tom, that's exactly what I do in the AJAX `success` callback using `$('#text2').val('some value');`.

Comment: ya i got it..i am accepting your answer..i will ask you Darin if i will face any problem.

Comment: hi i am getting error while compiling the file..will i need to import any js file in index.jsp? or what should i write in servlet named as someservlet, any solution please?

Comment: @tom, you have problems with your servlet? Maybe you should ask a separate question as it is no longer related to javascript and jQuery which is what your original question was about. As far as what script you should import in `index.jsp`, well, `jquery.js` is enough.

Comment: ya..i have asked in a separate question..please have a look Darin..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9158559/autocomplete-error-coming-in-jsp-ajax

Answer (score 1):

Capture the `TAB` key press in the javascript using `keycode`. Then use the ajax call to call your servlet

More about ajax

http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=474951

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one. Just call your function that will fill second textbox on second textbox blur event.

```
$('#secondtextbox').blur(function() {
  $.ajax({
          url: '/someservlet/',
          type: 'POST',
          data: { value: $('#firsttestbox').val() },
          success: function(result) {
                // when the AJAX succeeds update the value of the 
                // second textbox using the result returned by the server
                // In this example we suppose that the servlet returns
                // the following JSON: {"foo":"bar"}
                $(this).val(result.foo);
            }
        });    
});
```

Hope this helps